# Application crashes when pressing back in camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am having problem in my application.
Its crashing when I press back button in camera without capturing image.
I can not understand what is the problem.
Any one of you please give me solution for this.

This is code when button is pressed:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setMessage("From where to select Image?")
                           .setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   GlobalVariables.window="end";
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                try {
                                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                            SELECT_PICTURE);

                                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ane) {
                                    ane.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                   GlobalVariables.window="end";
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(new File(RespAdap.path.toString()+"/Attachment.png")));
                                                                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1337);

                                }
                           });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
```

This is code of onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                if(resultCode != 0)
                {
                 if (bitmap != null) {
                              bitmap.recycle(); // If bitmap is not null then here it will be recycled and set to null
                              bitmap = null;

                          }
        try{     
                 Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                 String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                 File fileObject = new File(selectedImagePath);
                 bitmap = decodeFile(fileObject);
                 img_selected.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 String val = getBase64Value(bitmap);
                 myBitmapImage=bitmap;
                 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                          Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                              int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                              String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                              fileExt = filePath.substring(filePath.length()-3);
                          }
                          cursor.close();
                          img_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
                 //new uploadImage().execute(val); 
                }
               }
               else if (requestCode == 1337) {
                if (data == null&&resultCode==-1) {
                try{File fileObject = new File(RespAdap.path.toString()+"/Attachment.png");
                    bitmap = decodeFile(fileObject);
                    //img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String val = getBase64Value(bitmap);
                      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(getCameraPhotoOrientation(getActivity(),Uri.fromFile(new File(RespAdap.path.toString()+"/Attachment.png")), RespAdap.path.toString()+"/Attachment.png"));
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                                                      matrix, true);
                     myBitmapImage=bitmap;
                     img_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     img_selected.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                } else {
                 Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                 int imageHeight = thumbnail.getHeight();
                 int imageWidth = thumbnail.getWidth();
                 Log.v("Log_tag", "Final image Height" + imageHeight);
                 Log.v("Log_tag", "Final image Width" + imageWidth);
                 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                             String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                             Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                 String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                                 fileExt = filePath.substring(filePath.length()-3);
                             }
                             cursor.close();
                             String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImage);
                             File fileObject = new File(selectedImagePath);
                             bitmap = decodeFile(fileObject);
                             //img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                             String val = getBase64Value(bitmap);
                             Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                                matrix.postRotate(getCameraPhotoOrientation(getActivity(), selectedImage, selectedImagePath));
                                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                                                              matrix, true);
                             myBitmapImage=bitmap;
                             img_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             img_selected.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
               }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I am testing on Galaxy Note 10.1. This is the logcat for that.

```
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747): Process: com.first.ogoing, PID: 30747
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=329017, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.first.ogoing/com.first.try_flymenu.ReponsiveList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:169)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at com.first.try_flymenu.adapter.RespChangImage.onActivityResult(RespChangImage.java:258)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:161)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5665)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
09-11 20:48:24.896: E/AndroidRuntime(30747):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: as in log `data` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nullpointerexception in your receiving activity:

at

`com.first.try_flymenu.adapter.RespChangImage.onActivityResult(RespChangImage.java:258)`

At line 258, it seems as you expect data to be returned that is not there.

You need to check in your `onActivityResult()` that `if(resultcode == RESULT_OK)` before handling the data.